# Perl and Regular expression; $1 is empty

Tags: regex, perl, regex-greedy

**Script:**

```
$aString = "This is Just a temp string just for fun";

print '^^^^^^^^' . "\n";

if( $aString =~ /^This\sis.*just/ )
{
    print $aString . " ->true<-\n" . "^^^^^^^^" ."$1";
}
else
{
    print $aString . " ->false<-\n" . "^^^^^^^^" ."$1"
}
```

**Output:**

> ^^^^^^^^
>
> This is Just a temp string just for fun ->true<-
>
> ^^^^^^^^

**Questions:**

1. Why $1 is empty?
2. How to know how much sub-expression in `aString` is matched?

Pls clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why $1 is empty?

Your expression has no capture groups (`()`) in it. Perhaps you mean:

```
$aString =~ /^This\sis(.*)just/
```

> How to know how much sub-expression in aString is matched?

Once you have captured some data, you can test it however you like.

Answer (score 2):

If you really didn't want to use a capture group (as mentioned in at least one other answer), you can also use the /p option on the regular expression and `${^MATCH}` instead of `$1`:

```
if( $aString =~ /^This\sis.*just/p )
{
    print $aString . " ->true<-\n" . "^^^^^^^^" ."${^MATCH}";
}
```

This is equivalent(?) to wrapping your entire regular expression in a capture group:

```
if( $aString =~ /(^This\sis.*just)/ )
{
    print $aString . " ->true<-\n" . "^^^^^^^^" ."$1";
}
```